# Moving server control libraries in .net solution from one folder to another

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to move some class libraries (server controls in a .NET 4.0 solution) from one folder in windows explorer to another.

How can I do this and not break anything in the actual .NET solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep them in the same solution, then do it from within Visual Studio.

If you want to remove them from a solution and add them to another, then remove them first (in VS) then move them, then add them to the other (in VS).

Comment: I want to make a Windows folder in the solution though, so this will have to be done via Windows Explorer.

Comment: No. Right click the solution (if you want the folder as part of the soution, and not part of a project - otherwise, right click the project) and click 'New Folder.'